# ORACLE: Cannot bind parameter to create table AS subquery

Tags: oracle, pdo

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ORA$PTT_collection_ids
        ON COMMIT PRESERVE DEFINITION AS (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT cms3_dc_language.collection_id AS "collection_id" 
        FROM 
            cms3_dc_language
        WHERE 
            cms3_dc_language.language = :language)
```

```
$sth->bindParam(":language", $language);
```

Gives an error when trying to bind :language...

**OCIBindByName: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number**

The bind works if the bound parameter is not part of the create table AS subquery e.g.

```
SELECT 
            DISTINCT cms3_dc_language.collection_id AS "collection_id" 
        FROM 
            cms3_dc_language
        WHERE 
            cms3_dc_language.language = :language
```

```
$sth->bindParam(":language", $language);
```

Comment: It sounds like the word/name that you are using is a reserved word. Check the value of the variable. If that's not the problem trying modiifying the name of the placeholder from language ( to languag for example)

Comment: @Kendle no it isn't that - it doesn't matter what the name of the bound parameter is in the subquery - it still throws the error - and "language" is fine as a bound parameter name outside of the subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do the same thing [using execute immediate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6a743e276434524d162d86c3c37e68c1) you can see the real issue:

> ORA-01027: bind variables not allowed for data definition operations

Although a bind variable is allowed as part of a query (obviously), here the query is a secondary factor, and it's the DDL that is the problem. You'd get the same error with a normal, non-temporary, table or a view, for instance.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I have worked around it by first creating the temporary table and then populating it separately with the same subquery.